# Show wiki excerpts in mobile app

Tags: feature-request, tags, android-app, tag-wiki-excerpt

I just tried to edit the tags of a question through the mobile app, but wanted to check the tag wiki excerpt for usage guidance first. If there is a way to see it in the app, I haven't figured it out.

I hereby **request that tag wiki excerpts/usage guidance be shown in the mobile app.** As hovering is not really a thing on touch screens, I suggest that the excerpt be shown on a long press while on the tag search/adding screen. (I'm amenable to other options, like adding a small button to the tag name when it shows up as a search result, so long as it's shown.)

This long press functionality can also be applied to tags shown on questions already asked, but I think it's more important to see the usage guidance when asking and editing.

Comment: @Sha slightly different -- that one wants the full wikis in the apps (which is also a good idea); this one asks for the wiki excerpts when asking/editing a question.

Comment: hmm... still don't think it warrants two different requests. Both are good ideas though.